# Explain to me this example that shows $L^1([a,b])$ is not closed under multiplication.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, examples-counterexamples, lebesgue-measure

This is an exercise of my course of Measure and Integration.

**The original question**

> Give an example that $f$ is Lebesgue integrable but $f^2$ is not.

**What I found:**

This is an example: $f:(0,1)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=1/\sqrt{x}$.

**What I Know:**
By the Chebichevy's inequality we have that for each $\lambda>0$ 
$$
\infty>m(\{x\in(0,1): f(x)=1/\sqrt{x}\leq\lambda \})\geq\frac{1}{\lambda}\int_{(0,1)}f
$$
so $f$ is integrable. ( $\int |f|<\infty$ ).

**What I don't understand:**

Why $f^2=1/x$ **is not** Lebesgue integrable? Furthermore give me another example for a function that is not Lebesgue integrable and tell me why.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem so far? What have you tried? In what context did you encounter this problem? The more you can tell us, the more easily we will be able to tailor our answers to your needs.

Comment: @CameronBuie I have edited the post. Now is clear? Can you help me with this?

Comment: $\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{x} = \lim_{a \to 0+} \int_a^1 \frac{dx}{x} = \lim_{a \to 0+} \log 1 - \log a = +\infty$.

Answer (score 2):

$f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$, $x \in (0,1)$. But I'm sure this question is a duplicate.

Comment: but, $1/\sqrt{x}$ is integrable? (I will delete this, so)

Comment: It is "almost" the derivative of $\sqrt{x}$...

Comment: But... Can you argue using the definition of Lebesgue integrable functions? Why $\int 1/\sqrt{x}<\infty$ and why $\int 1/x=\infty$?

Comment: $$
\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}} = \int_0^\infty \mathcal{L}^1 \left( \left\{ x \in (0,1) \mid \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}>t \right\} \right) \, dt = \int_1^\infty \frac{dt}{t^2}.
$$
See also here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Improper_integral#Improper_Riemann_integrals_and_Lebesgue_integrals

Comment: I have edited my post. Now my doubt is clear?